# Unable to perform root login

Tags: ssh, login, remote-access

When I try to ssh into my friends computer in the same LAN with his host-name and IP I am able to login successfully. But when I try to login using the root user password it shows me the following error. What could be the possible reason?

```
ssh root@x.x.x.x
root@x.x.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@x.x.x.x's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
root@x.x.x.x's password: 
Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

Comment: SSH default configuration don't allow to log as root.

Comment: Then how can i change the configuration?

Comment: In the host `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` add (or modify) the line: 

`PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: Thanks for that. I wish to know whether there exists any other options available to ssh without enabling this thing in sshd_config

Comment: Well, maybe there is one I know not, but it would be really strange (from a security point of view), if you could be able to login as root on some computer which don't allow it explicitly. Anyway, why logging as root ? If you use an account member of the sudoers group, you will be able to do anything you could do as root.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the sudoers group. Thanks for mentioning that. I will research on that.

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways to configure SSH. Al three ways have the same options wich will be passed as arguments to SSH.

1-System wide configuration file: /etc/ssh/ssh_config

2-Personal configuration file: ~/.ssh/config

3-Command line arguments

Comment: Yes, but you can't setup the `login as root` permission from the client side which obviously what's OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the SSH root connection is activated in the remote laptop !

Open the file */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

> vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Turn the  *PermitRootLogin* option from No to Yes

> PermitRootLogin Yes

Reload the ssh service

> /etc/init.d/sshd reload

Hope it helps ...